# Add prefix to JSR 352 Batch API tables

Tags: java, jsr352, jberet

I'm currently using JSR 352 Batch API in Jboss/CDI environment (JBeret implementation).

I didn't find into JSR and JBeret documentation how to add prefix the specifics batchs tables (STEP_EXECUTION, JOB_EXECUTION, JOB_INSTANCE ...).

Example : JOB_INSTANCE => BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE

Does someone have an idea ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JBeret job repository tables are internal to the implementation and their names are not changeable. Why do you want to change job repository table names?

Update 1/20/2017: this feature is under consideration in project JBeret, as issue [JBERET-298](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBERET-298).

Comment: Thanks you cheng for that quick answer, i just wanted to separate the batch api table from other tables of my database. Or can i use a separate datasource ?

Comment: Yes, in WildFly or JBoss EAP, you can configure the batch subsystem datasource in either CLI command line or Admin Console.

Comment: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Batch+%28JSR-352%29+Subsystem+Configuration